# best practice to validate input java

Tags: java, validation, input, hashmap

I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about validating input from a user. My assignment is to execute commands based on a textual input from the user. My only concern is that there can be many variations of commands that are acceptable.

For example these commands are all acceptable and do the same thing, "show the game board"

> sh board,
>   sho board,
>   show board,
>   show bo,
>   sho bo,
>   sh bo

There are about 10 other commands that share this similar property so I was wondering what would be the best practice of going about validating a users input?

Should I store all the different combinations in a hashmap?

Comment: Putting all valid combinations in a hashmap would get clunky real fast, and you'll also have to keep updating it as you run into more valid combos. You could enforce more strictness by providing the user with a fixed set of commands to use, or let him pick numbers corresponding to commands. Reg ex is another more viable solution.

Comment: I totally get what you're saying and thats why I'm asking, I don't want it to be clunky. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to restrict the commands. The purpose of the exercise is to be able to handle all the variations.

Comment: I see. I posted a little reg ex snippet to help you get started.

Comment: OP, Curious as to how you ended up doing this.

Comment: I ended up using a switch statement to test the first word with a second switch statement nested inside to test for the second word.

Answer (score 1):

Look into regex (regular expressions). These are great for when you want to use values that are not necessarily complete.

For example: 
Say I type "shutdo"
With regex you can make your program understand that anything after the string "shutd" means to powerOff()

Comment: I full-heartedly disagree with you. This is the job of a simple lexer, which in parts might be written in regex, but seeing regexes as the solution for a system with maybe 10 commands that might each take about 5 different arguments... this is going to be completely unmanageable right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

If the commands are very specific and limited, I would just add all of them into some data structure (hash being one of them).

If the problem was that you're supposed to understand what the user input is supposed to do, then I would say find the pattern using either regex or a simple pattern validation (looks like they're all two words, first starting with "sh" and second starting with "bo").

But honestly, ~15 commands aren't that big of deal in terms of space/efficiency.

**Edit:**

> There are about 10 other commands that share this similar property

If this means 10 *more* commands like "show board", then I would say store it in hash. But if I misunderstood you and you mean that there are 10 other commands that do similar things ("set piece", "set pie", "se pi", etc), then RegEx is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the minimum command allowed length is 2.
So first you check if the length of the term is at least 2.

Next, you can loop over the available commands,
and stop at the first that starts with the term, for example:

```
List<String> commands = Arrays.asList("show", "create", "delete");
for (String command : commands) {
    if (command.startsWith(term)) {
        // found a match, command is: command
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, there are N distinct commands, which can be combined. It shall be allowed to abbreviate each command as long it stays unambiguous.

If this is the case, the following methods `expandCommands(String)` and `expandCommand(String)` will normalize each command part.

```
public class Main {
    static Set<String> availableCommands = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            "show",
            "board",
            "btest"
    ));


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> testData = Arrays.asList(
                "sh board",
                "sho board",
                "show board",
                "show bo",
                "sho bo",
                "sh bo"
        );


        String expected = "show board";
        for (String test : testData) {
            String actual = expandCommands(test);

            if (!expected.equals(actual)) {
                System.out.println(test + "\t"+  actual);
            }

        }


        try {
            expandCommands("sh b");
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!"not unique command: b".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        try {
            expandCommands("sh asd");
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!"unknown command: asd".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }


    }

    private static String expandCommands(String aInput) throws Exception {
        final String[] commandParts = aInput.split("\\s+");


        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (String commandPart : commandParts) {
            String command = expandCommand(commandPart);

            result.append(command).append(" ");
        }


        return result.toString().trim();
    }

    private static String expandCommand(final String aCommandPart) throws Exception {
        String match = null;

        for (String candidate : availableCommands) {
            if (candidate.startsWith(aCommandPart)) {
                if (match != null) {
                    throw new Exception("not unique command: " + aCommandPart);
                }

                match = candidate;
            }
        }


        if (match == null) {
            throw new Exception("unknown command: " + aCommandPart);
        }

        return match;
    }

}
```

The `Set<String> availableCommands` contains all possible commands.

Every part of the input command is checked, if it is the start of exactly one available command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reg-ex matching to validate input. E.g., the pattern below will match anything that starts with `sh` followed by 0 or more characters, then a `space` and then `bo` followed by 0 or more chars.

```
public class Validator {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    String pattern = "sh[\\w]* bo[\\w]*";
    System.out.println(args[0].matches(pattern));
  }
}
```